# Changing directory and file permissions

Tags: permissions, files, directory, chown

I am trying to change the owner and group of a directory that happens to be on a mounted drive. I can run sudo chown and sudo chgrp on the directory however, when I look at the group and owner, nothing changes. I get no failures in the output. Am I missing something? Is there any extra step because it is mounted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could not change ownership or permissions on ntfs partition the way you're trying to do it.

You could only mount it with required `uid` of user you want to be the owner of the partition.

Find out your user `uid` and `gid` by:

```
$ cat /etc/passwd | grep $(echo $USER)
```

Find out your ntfs partition UUID by `blkid` command execution.

Mount your partition in `/etc/fstab` with your user's permissions and ownership:

```
UUID=1EB89832B8980B03    /mnt/super    ntfs    rw,uid=1000,gid=1000    0   0
```

Add also `noauto` option if you do not want it to be mounted automatically at boot.

Even binding

```
sudo mount --bind /mnt/super/test ~/test/newtest -o rw,uid=0,gid=0
```

will change nothing. Ownership will remain as you specified there in `/etc/fstab` or as it is now in case of mounting it using nautilus or other file manager.

If you want everyone reading and writing permissions on that partition, you could change `uid` and `gid` to `65534`:

```
$ cat /etc/passwd | grep nobody
nobody:x:65534:65534:nobody:/nonexistent:/usr/sbin/nologin
```

in `/etc/fstab`:

```
UUID=1EB89832B8980B03 /mnt/super ntfs rw,uid=65534,gid=65534 0 0
```

Also, you could find some info about mapping windows/linux users [here](https://www.tuxera.com/community/ntfs-3g-advanced/ownership-and-permissions/). But I didn't try it and could not answer if it works as you want.

Comment: Thank You! This worked perfectly!